# Conexão com o proxy: HTTP 407 Autenticação de Proxy Obrigatória

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy

Criei um projeto para ASP NET em que desejo obter os dados de um endereço a partir do CEP consultando por uma chamada da url em um webservice.

Em minha máquina funciona normalmente, porém na máquina que trabalho, há a necessidade de autenticação de rede. Quando dou o submit no form, a exceção é acionada com a seguinte mensagem:

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (407) Autenticação de Proxy Obrigatória.

Abaixo o código que tentei usar para realizer a conexão a partir de outras soluções gringas do StackOverflow, porém sem êxito:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("XX.XX.XX.XXX", 999);
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXX", "*********");
```

Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu costumo configurar proxy com o .NET da seguinte maneira:

Crio uma classe que herda de IWebProxy:

```
namespace MinhaEmpresa.MeuProduto.Web.Proxy {
    public class MyProxy : IWebProxy
    {
        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get
            {               
                return new NetworkCredential("USUARIO", "UMA_SENHA_SEGURA");
            }
            set { }
        }

        public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {           
            return new Uri("http://host:port");
        }

        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
        {       
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

No Web.config da aplicação, deve-se configurar o proxy criado:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
        <module type="MinhaEmpresa.MeuProduto.Web.Proxy.MyProxy, MinhaEmpresa.MeuProduto.Web"/>
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

Os parâmetros do atributo type da tag module são, nessa ordem:

- Nome da classe que implementa `IWebProxy` (no exemplo `MinhaEmpresa.MeuProduto.Web.Proxy.MyProxy`)
- Nome do Assembly que a classe que implementa IWebProxy está contida (nome da DLL, sem a extensão).

A vantagem dessa solução é que as configurações do proxy podem estar em qualquer lugar: em um banco de dados, no .config da aplicação, em um XML, etc. Sugiro não deixá-las *Hard Code* como no exemplo.

Comment: Em conjunto com essa resposta:  http://codigosfontes.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/obtendo-o-html-de-uma-pagina-com-c.html e essa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954635/the-servicepointmanager-does-not-support-proxies-of-scheme , sua solução foi simples e resolveu meu problema. Contudo não consegui obter os dados usando o objeto WebClient, teoricamente mais prático, informando que ocorreu um erro no WebClient(); Sabe algo sobre isso?

Comment: Você não conseguiu rodar sem a última função porque está implementando uma interface (contrato), quando faz isso é obrigado a escrever os métodos que ela declara. Leia mais em https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx. Vou editar a resposta para explicar melhor o `.config`.

Comment: Quanto ao WebClient, sugiro abrir outra questão com seu problema específico.

Answer (score 0):

Tive exatamente o mesmo erro que o user21846, na minha casa o código funcionava normalmente, porem no serviço apresentava a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (407) Autenticação de Proxy Obrigatória.

Mas solucionei de uma forma mais simples, adicionei o seguinte trecho no arquivo "App.config"

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Obs: Colei dentro da tag "configuration"

Assim o código rodou assim como na minha casa, com este trecho ele simplesmente pega o proxy padrão da maquina.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219412/7986223)